# Determine if action is on member or on collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I have been trying to find a clean way to determine wether an action (in a rails controller) applies on members or on collection.

For example when you declare in routes.rb

```
resources :projects
```

You get the following methods defined "on collections":

- index
- create
- new

and the following are defined on "on members":

- update
- show
- delete

I am trying to find a way to leverage this great pattern in views for example:

```
<% if @controller.action.applies_on_members? %>
  <%= link_to :destroy, :method => "delete", :confirm => "RU Sure" %>
  <%= link_to :show, "show" %>
<% end %>
```

Similarly this could be useful in before_filters

```
before_filter :find_project, :only_on_members => true
```

*Currently* I have to do the following:

```
before_filter :find_project, :except => [:new, :create, :index, :export_all, :destroy_all, :archive_all]
```

This is quite annoying and my idea is that all such actions share a common behavior: they are defined on *collections*.

Does anyone have an idea of how to achieve this in clean way ?

**NB: The reason I ask this question is because I am looking for something scalable in terms of development, such that the behavior of before_filters or some partials is automatically inherited by new custom actions.**

Who never had to write down something like

```
<% unless ["new", "index", "some_other_action1", "some_other_action2", "some_other_action3", "some_other_action4"].include? @controller.action_name %>
  <%= link_to "Destroy", :project, :method => :delete %>  
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost a year after posting this question, I know have found a reasonable solution for this question.

If we look at what `on => :member` and `on => :collection` really do, the difference is basically that  `on => :member` generates a path including the `:id` param, whereas the `on => :collection` version does not.

A simple solution would then to test whether `params[:id]` is blank or not in a custom method. It would look like this (say in `application_controller.rb`):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def on_member?
    !params[:id].blank?
  end

  helper_method :on_member? #method will be accessible in views
end
```

As described in [this post](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/before-filter-wisdom) for example, we can do something like this in a before_filter:

```
before_filter :find_project, :if => :on_member?
```

In views, this allows me to check the kind of method like so:

```
<% if on_member? %>
  <%= link_to :destroy, :method => "delete", :confirm => "RU Sure" %>
  <%= link_to :show, "show" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the pattern on operating on collections and their entries is part of [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) which is one of the pillars of Rails. What you've identified is essentially what REST calls **collections** and **entries**. In theory, you can apply [the most common HTTB verbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) on either the collection, or an entry within that collection, where: **GET**; retrieve, **PUT**; replace, **POST**; create and **DELETE**; destroy. Although it's a little unclear what POST would do on a single entry.

In practise, and in Rails, however, you usually use those you've identified:

- Collections

  - Create entry (**POST**)
  - View entries (**GET**)
- Entry

  - Update entry (**PUT**)
  - Show entry (**GET**)
  - Delete entry (**DELETE**)

These are the RESTful routes Rails adds. However, as you know Rails also boxes two other actions to implement a user page which can provide the necessary data to these endpoints. (**new**, **edit**),

It's rare I see people coming down to these definitions. As I see it there's at least two ways to go about this problem if you really want to solve it (see bottom of the post):

You could monkey-patch ["_normalize_callback_options"](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d42d97d2e3f0bdef2163cc14daa181903e0b198d/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb#L33-42) to get the exact syntax you proposed. This is relatively straight-forward, but if upstream changes anything about the structure, you have to change your patch, thus it's not very sustainable. Therefore I would not recommend that approach, no matter how tasteful the syntastic sugar looks. Of course you could also try to commit this upstream, but it's unlikely to be accepted due to the reasons mentioned below. :-)

Instead I'd put your definitions in an initializer: `config/initializer/rest.rb`

```
ENTRY_ACTIONS      = [:edit, :new, :show, :delete, :update]
COLLECTION_ACTIONS = [:create, :index]
```

Then use them in your filters like:

```
before_filter :find_project, only: ENTRY_ACTIONS
```

For access in your views, add an `entry_action?` and `collection_action?` method to your application helper:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def entry_action?
    ENTRY_ACTIONS.include?(controller.action_name.to_sym)
  end

  def collection_action?
    COLLECTION_ACTIONS.include?(controller.action_name.to_sym)
  end
end
```

Then in your views:

```
<% if entry_action? %>
   # code
<% end %>
```

I wouldn't extract this to constants myself, but just write the array directly since it's much more clear in my opinion to read when I come back later. Furthermore, most people would have to think twice every time they encounter these methods which is far from optimal.

Comment: [Question Updated] Thank you for your answer. I was actually looking for a scalable solution, such that when I add a new action, my views and my controllers do not have to be changed too much in terms of befor_filters and actions displayed to users.

Comment: Isn't the constants solution fine for exactly that? Although I'd still say it's a code smell if you have controllers with so many actions you want to do that. In this case passing identical arrays in different controllers to `before_filter` wouldn't be violating DRY, it'd be creating readable code.

Comment: Well it would solve (the easy) part of the problem. The other part is the custom actions I create for every controller

Comment: I'm really not sure what you want. Could you try to update your question? It seems like you're fighting against Rails from more than one angle, but I'm not sure exactly what you are fighting.

Comment: Question updated. I just want to be able to say "This apply to all actions defined on collections" in consistent way with the way you add custom routes in routes.rb: get "archive_all", :on => :collection

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-collection

Answer (score 0):

You're taking a very common problem that's already solved in Rails for us and pretty much turning it upside down. Rather than asking the controller about its state all over your application, you should [tell](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/27572137956/tell-dont-ask) your views and controllers to do what it needs to do however it knows how to do it.

Since you already know for sure that the `index`, `create` and `new` actions apply to "collections" and that `update`, `show` and `delete` apply to "members", you should define each respective controller actions and views to work with such forms of resources.

Going back to the examples you've given, the links should be defined in a partial and have the appropriate view template render the partial.

Your `before_filter` should be written as `before_filter :find_project, :only => [:update, :show, :delete]`.

Just the thought of seeing calls to `@controller.action.applies_on_members?` all over the place in your application raises a flag in my mind that you need to rethink your design. Again, you're trying to solve a problem that Rails already takes care of for you.

Comment: Thanks. I know about before_filters on common usage like you describe. I am looking for a scalable solution for my problem. I am not sure to see how this is already solved by rails

Comment: You're already defeating "scalability" by foreseeing the need to add  so many actions in a controller. Especially since it's apparently come to a point where you need to "scale" this problem of adding more and more actions on a controller. You're just digging yourself deeper.